# Binding ninject via name

Tags: c#, ninject

I have a ninject problem where I am using the same interface on multiple types to provide a config class for my application.

The entry point classes (below) that start that application are returned from the ninject kernel and I have a named `Config` dependency on that class.

```
    public ProcessA(ILogger logger, [Named("TypeA")] IConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configProvider = configProvider;
    }

    public ProcessB(ILogger logger, [Named("TypeB")] IConfigProvider configProvider)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _configProvider = configProvider;
    }
```

And then in my bindings

```
        Bind<IConfigProvider>().To<ProcessA>().Named("TypeA");
        Bind<IConfigProvider>().To<ProcessB>().Named("TypeB");
```

Further down the processing line `ProcessA` and `ProcessB` share some classes that need an `IConfigProvider` but when the `ProcessA` or `ProcessB` gets to that point ninject cannot resolve the dependancy. I can't make it a named dependency at that point because the classes are used by both processors.

I could pass the concrete `Config` class down from `ProcessA` and `ProcessB` removing the constructor dependency but that doesn't seem the right way to do it.

## **EDIT 1 (from BatteryBackupUnit's answer)**

I removed the named references and added the below which seems to do the trick. Found a method on the following question [Ninject Bind When Ancestor Of Type T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921890/ninject-bind-when-ancestor-of-type-t) but I had to add in a check for `request.Target == null` else it wouldnt work when I got an instance of `ProcessA` and `ProcessB` from the ninject kernel.

```
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IConfigProvider>()
            .To<TypeAConfigProvider>()
            .When(request => HasAncestorOfType<ProcessA>(request));

        Bind<IConfigProvider>()
            .To<TypeBConfigProvider>()
            .When(request => HasAncestorOfType<ProcessB>(request));
    }

    private static bool HasAncestorOfType<T>(IRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null || request.Target == null) 
            return false;

        if (request.Target.Member.ReflectedType == typeof(T)) 
            return true;

        return HasAncestorOfType<T>(request.ParentRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Looks good to me. But why didn't you use/extend the `WhenAnyAncestorMatches` method?

Comment: Can't resolve the method?!

Comment: Strange. It should be there, though, for example it's used in ninject's tests [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject.Test/Integration/ConditionalBindingTests.cs).

Comment: I know, weird. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [contextual binding](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) mechanism to achieve that.
See [IBindingWhenSyntax.cs](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/c18c3120ba0cc93e79c1d7a56785866ed1bc6669/src/Ninject/Syntax/IBindingWhenSyntax.cs) for all available methods.
How about `WhenAnyAncestorNamed`?

Alternatively, there's the `WhenInjectedInto<>` binding which would be used like:

```
Bind<IConfigProvider>().To<ConfigA>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<ProcessA>();
```

Now since you don't actually want to inject it directly into `ProcessA` you'd have to use a `When` condition like `WhenInjectedIntoAncestor<Process>()`. You can create this yourself - as an extension method extending from the `WhenAnyAncestorMatches` extension method. Also see [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding#specifying-constraints-on-the-type-binding-using-arbitrary-elements-of-the-resolution-request-context)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, think it's sent me on the right path. Can you check my edit please?